# Ubuntu Software Centre not opening on elementary OS

Tags: appcenter

I would like to use Ubuntu Software Centre just because it has more apps than AppCenter does and is just more enjoyable to use. However every time I try to open it, its icon appears in a dock and then it just shuts down and disappears. I could not find a fix anywhere. I tried installing it by both just downloading it from AppCenter and by `sudo apt-get install software-center` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the new shop of Ubuntu, the Gnome Software:

You can install via the command line: `sudo apt install gnome-software`

Or via AppCenter, looking for `gnome-software`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

`sudo apt install gnome-software`

GNOME Software is set to replace  Ubuntu Software Center in 16.04

The program can be used to add and manage repositories as well as UbuntuPersonal Package Archives (PPA). Ubuntu replaced its previous Ubuntu Software Center program with GNOME Software starting with Ubuntu 16.04

Source: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Software

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies: gnome-software : Depends: appstream but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.